# Parent Child Relationship Causes Class Does Not Name Type Error

Tags: c++

If I have a simple two-class relationship like this, I will get this error: `‘Parent’ does not name a type`. I **do** understand why this error occurs, but how can I prevent this?

parent.h

```
#ifndef PARENT_H
#define PARENT_H

#include "child.h"

class Parent {
        Child b;
};

#endif
```

child.h

```
#ifndef CHILD_H
#define CHILD_H

#include "parent.h"

class Child {
        Parent a;
};

#endif
```

impl.cpp

```
#include "parent.h"

Parent b;

int main() {

}
```

Comment: Also see my [recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644151/can-i-make-c-code-structure-see-each-other/37644172#37644172).

Comment: Please do a Googe/Bing search on "C++ Circular dependency"

Comment: If I do the forward declaration of `Parent` right above `Child`, I get this error: `field ‘a’ has incomplete type ‘Parent’`.